# Find the maximum possible area of a certain right triangle

Tags: geometry, inequality, optimization

I want to find the maximum possible area of a right triangle with hypotenuse $=10$.
My approach so far: let $x,y$ be the lengths of the two sides adjacent to the right angle; then $$100=x^2+y^2$$

Area $=\frac{xy}{2}$, so by the substitution method I got equality. But my result is wrong (probably I made a mistake in the equality), could someone show what to do?

Comment: what do you mean by: "I got equality"?

Comment: If you mean that you found $x=y$, that is correct. Without seeing your steps we cannot comment on your work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are already some good answers, but as the question is tagged [geometry](/questions/tagged/geometry), I wanted to post a bit less algebraic solution (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/455944/26306)).

**Hint:**

- Take a circle of diameter $10$, then all right triangles with the hypotenuse of length $10$ can be inscribed into it as shown in the picture below.
- Considering that $$\mathrm{area} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\mathrm{height} \cdot \mathrm{base},$$ where $\mathrm{base} = 10$ and $\mathrm{height}$ is marked using a red dashed line, can you see which triangle will have the biggest area?

$\hspace{70pt}$[image: right triangles]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Beautiful. Which program produced the graphic?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thank you, the program was [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

Answer (score 5):

$$(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy=100-2xy\ge 0\iff \frac{xy}{2}\le 25$$

with equality iff $x=y>0$, i.e. $2x^2=100\iff x=y=\sqrt{50}=5\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: oh, it was really stupid mistake)
Thx a lot

Comment: problem solving takeaway: try to relate the constraint and your objective in an inequality somehow

Answer (score 2):

As you said, we have $100 = x^2+y^2$ so that $y= \sqrt{100-x^2}$ and thus the area is $$A= \frac{xy}{2}=\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{100-x^2}.$$
Now, let $f(x)= \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{100-x^2}$ and maximize this function over $x\geq 0$, e.g. by looking when $f'(x)=0$ to find its critical points.

Answer (score 2):

Let the non-hypotenuse sides of the triangle be $(a,b)$.  Then the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and the area is $A = \frac{ab}{2}$.  So

$$a^2+b^2 = 100\\
A^2 = \frac14 a^2b^2 = \frac14 a^2 (100-a^2) \\
$$

Maximizing $A^2$ maximizes $A$, and
$$
\frac{d(A^2)}{da} =\frac14( 200a -4a^3)
$$
which is zero at $a = \sqrt{50}$ making $b=\sqrt{50}$ as well and the area $A = \frac12\sqrt{50}^2 = 25$

Answer (score 2):

Let's use Lagrange Multipliers as this is a Maxima-Minima problem. We have the constraint $x^2+y^2=100$ and the function to maximize is ${{x \cdot y} \over 2}$

Taking the gradients, derivatives with respect to both variables, and equating we get a system of equations.

$$2x=\lambda \cdot {y \over 2}$$
$$2y=\lambda \cdot {x \over 2}$$

Which simplifies to

$$4 \cdot x= \lambda \cdot y$$
$$4 \cdot y= \lambda \cdot x$$

The equations are symmetric so we know that $x=y$

Substituting this into the constraint $x^2+y^2=100$, we get

$$2x^2=100 \Rightarrow x=5 \cdot \sqrt2$$
and
$$2y^2=100 \Rightarrow y= 5 \cdot \sqrt2$$

So the maximum area is ${25}$

Comment: there are should be $x^2+y^2=10^2$

Comment: @МузаффарШакаров Op mentions $10$ first, so I solved for a hypotenuse of 10.

Comment: yup. but in formula $a^2+b^2=c^2$ in right angled triangle

Comment: i mean the square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides

Comment: @МузаффарШакаров Sorry I took so long to make the edit! Was on an errand. Thanks :)

Comment: Lol -- way overkill (simple geometric intuition suffices), but still +1

Answer (score 0):

A little geometry:

Draw a line and a circle with radius $5$, 
and center on the line.

Call the points of intersection of circle and line $A$ and $B$.

This circle is the $Thales$ circle, diameter AB. Take any point on the circle, call it $C$.

All vertices,$\, C$, of right triangles with hypotenuse 10 are on this circle.

Area of a triangle: $ Area$ = $1/2 × base × height$.

1) $Base = 10$, given.

2)$ Maximal \, height $ of triangles with vertices on the circle is  clearly the

$ radius = 5$;

($ABC$ is isosceles in this case).

$Maximal \, area = 1/2 × base × height = 1/2 × 10 × 5 = 25$.

Comments welcome!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The area of triangle $ABC$ is just $\Delta ABO + \Delta BOC$. If $\angle BOC = \theta$, the area is:

$$\frac{1}{2} r^2 \sin \theta + \frac{1}{2}r^2 \sin(180 - \theta) = \frac{1}{2}r^2 \big( \sin \theta + \sin(180 - \theta) \big) = \frac{1}{2}r^2 (2 \sin \theta) = r^2 \sin \theta$$

where we have used the identity $\sin \theta = \sin(180 - \theta)$.

The maximum value of $\sin \theta$ is $1$, so the maximum area is $r^2$. In this case, $r = 5$ so the maximum area is $25$.

This occurs when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $90º$, so $\Delta ABC$ must in fact be isoceles.

---

Alternatively, if $A = (-5,0)$, $B = (5 \cos t, 5 \sin t)$, $C = (5,0)$, then the area of $\Delta ABC$ using the shoelace formula is:

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    5 & 0  \\
    5 \cos t & 5 \sin t \\
    -5 & 0 \\
    5 & 0 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

so the area is: $$\frac{1}{2} \big((25 \sin t + 0 + 0) - (0 + -25 \sin t + 0) \big) = 25 \sin t$$

which takes the maximum value $25(1)$ when $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$, again.

The area of triangle $ABC$ is can also be computed using determinants:

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    5 & 0 & 1 \\
    5 \cos t & 5 \sin t & 1 \\
    -5 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

which when computed, gives:

$$\frac{1}{2} \left((25 \sin t + 0 + 0) - (-25 \sin t + 0 + 0) \right) = 25 \sin t.$$